# CF7 - Validate list of serial numbers in textarea form field against database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am running CF7 on a webpage. the webpage accepts serial numbers for a product with a textarea box restricted to 1010 characters. Users are requested to input 10 digit serial numbers by hitting enter after each serial number.

I want to take this entry and validate the entry against a list of serial numbers in myphpadmin database. If a duplicate is found, the textarea box just needs to be highlighted to state that a duplicate serial was found.

If it is at all possible to highlight the specific serial number that would be great but the previous requirement will suffice for now.

Any help in providing a complete script is much appreciated.

If this cannot be done in CF7, then is this possible in MySQL? I have separated out the textarea serial number entries from this same form into separate rows and inserted them into a new database that contains just the list of serial numbers. This new database is populated every time the form is submitted.

Comment: I assume that's "Contact Form 7", and you've not mis-categorized a ColdFusion question .. right?  As for the question itself, sound like you need AJAX ...

Comment: Yes this is 'contact form 7' running on 'Wordpress ' with 'elementor' as the theme.

Comment: I do have a shortcode plugin installed into Wordpress that allows me to run filter and function scripts.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Hi Igor, I have currently have a script that runs using the shortcode plugin that checks a field value against a database.

Comment: function is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $fieldValue) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/wp-contact-form-7-to-database-extension-master/CFDBFormIterator.php');
    $exp = new CFDBFormIterator();
    $atts = array();
    $atts['show'] = $fieldName;
    $atts['filter'] = "$fieldName=$fieldValue";
    $atts['unbuffered'] = 'true';
    $exp->export($formName, $atts);
    $found = false;
    while ($row = $exp->nextRow()) {
        $found = true;
    }
    return $found;
}

Comment: function my_validate_serial1($result, $tag) {
    $formName = 'RTX_Test_Form'; // Change to name of the form containing this field
    $fieldName = 'SerialNumber1'; // Change to your form's unique field name
    $errorMessage = 'serial has already been submitted'; // Change to your error message
    $name = $tag['name'];
    if ($name == $fieldName) {
        if (is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $_POST[$name])) {
            $result->invalidate($tag, $errorMessage);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

Comment: thats what I have but it checks only a value string and does not include linebreaks for a textarea field. It works for a string on a single line in text field.